# Create and use a custom username validator for a registration form

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

currently I'm attempting to create a custom validator to validate usernames. Django only provides two validators: `ASCIIUsernameValidator` and `UnicodeUsernameValidator`. But both of them accept special characters like @, but I want to accept only alphanumeric characters (A-Za-z0-9) and underscores.

I did read the [validator documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/validators/) and I believe that something like this should work:

```
# project_name/validators.py
from django.core import validators
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
@deconstructible
class AlphanumericUsernameValidator(validators.RegexValidator):
    regex = r'^[\w]+$'
    message = _(
        'Enter a valid username. This value may contain only English letters, '
        'numbers and underscores.'
    )
    flags = re.ASCII
```

But how would I actually use it? I checked and AbstractUser contains this line: `username_validator = UnicodeUsernameValidator()`. Would I have to create an AbstractUser like below (not sure if I even can make one because I already have some users registered)?

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from project_name.validators import AlphaNumericUsernameValidator
class User(AbstractUser):
    username_validator = AlphaNumericUsernameValidator()
```

Would I have to create a custom AbstractUser? Or is there some other simpler way that doesn't require the creation of one just to change a single validator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create your own User model just like that:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        validators=[AlphaNumericUsernameValidator],
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
    )
```

Don't forget to define it in settings.py in `AUTH_USER_MODEL` variable.

Also, you probably need another regexp

```
regex = r'^[\w][\w\d_]+$'
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see the difference between the two regexps? \w already includes characters/numbers/underscores by itself, so `[\w]` and `[\w\d_]` are basically the same thing?